# MongoDB: all full leaf path

Tags: java, mongodb

Having a Document, I would like to obtain in Java the list of all full paths, only for the leafs.

For example, having this Document:

```
{A : {
    B : {
        D : "d"
    }
    C : {
        E : "e",
        F : "f"
    }
}
```

I would like to obtain this `List<String>`:

```
"A.B.D",
"A.C.E",
"A.C.F"
```

Is there a functionality into some "mongodb" library to do this?
How could I write it manually without using recursion?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

I used the power of `Gson` library to transfor the `Document` into a `json` and after read it with using `com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader`.

The code could be better with more performance, but for my necessity this code is ok, I just have to read only few Documents.

```
public static List<String> leafPaths(Document document) {
    String json = gson.toJson(document);
    List<String> leafPaths = new ArrayList<>();
    try (JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(json))) {
        // scorro tutti gli elemento dello json
        while (true) {
            JsonToken token = reader.peek();
            switch (token) {
                case BEGIN_ARRAY:
                    reader.beginArray();
                    break;
                case END_ARRAY:
                    reader.endArray();
                    break;
                case BEGIN_OBJECT:
                    reader.beginObject();
                    break;
                case END_OBJECT:
                    reader.endObject();
                    break;
                case NAME:
                    reader.nextName();
                    break;
                case STRING:
                    reader.nextString();
                    leafPaths.add(reader.getPath());
                    break;
                case NUMBER:
                    reader.nextDouble();
                    leafPaths.add(reader.getPath());
                    break;
                case BOOLEAN:
                    reader.nextBoolean();
                    leafPaths.add(reader.getPath());
                    break;
                case NULL:
                    reader.nextNull();
                    break;
                case END_DOCUMENT:
                    // tutti i campi 
                    return leafPaths.stream().map(field -> field.substring(2)).collect(toList());
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return leafPaths;
    }
}
```